# Como instalar o PIP no Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Estou tentando instalar o *PIP* de acordo com a documentação *Python*. Ele é instalado, porém não funciona.

Sempre acontece isso:

> pip' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa
>   operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 5):

Se o Python já esta nas variáveis de ambiente é só fazer assim:

```
python -m pip install -U nome_pacote
```

Se não estiver:

```
<pasta_onde_esta_instalado>\python.exe -m pip install -U nome_pacote
```

Answer (score 3):

É bem provável que você tenha instalado o Python dentro da pasta `C:\Programs and Files` ou `C:\Programs and Files (x64)` (ou outra pasta sem permissão de escrita), ou seja o seu usuário não tem permissão de escrever nestas pastas, logo mesmo após você pensar que instalou é provável que outra coisa tenha ocorrido.

O ideal para facilitar seria instalar talvez na raiz, ou na pasta do seu usuário, ou seja primeiro terá que remover o Python e depois instalar novamente e trocar o local da instalação.

Outra maneira de instalar, se é o que deseja, é instalar o `pip` com privilégios elevados

### Executar cmd como administrador Windows 7

Abra o menu iniciar e o no campo de busca digite `cmd`, quando aparecer nos programas o `cmd` clique com o botão direito do mouse/rato e selecione `Executar como administrador`

[image: win7]

### Executar cmd como administrador Windows 8 e 10

> **Nota:** No win8 provavelmente funcione, no Win10 não sei se esta opção aparece em todos, talvez tenha sido substituida pelo PowerShell

Clique com o botão direito do mouse/rato no Menu Iniciar e selecione a opção `prompt de comando (admin)`:

[image: prompt win8]

### Windows 10 e powershell como administrador

Talvez o seu Win10 possa não ter o prompt de comando nos itens do menu, mas o powershell é capaz de fazer o mesmo que o cmd (e muito mais), então clique com o botão direito do mouse/rato no Menu Iniciar e selecione a opção `Windows PowerShell (Admin)`:

[image: win10]

---

Agora baixe o https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py e depois execute e dependendo de onde baixou use o `cd` para navegar, exemplo:

```
cd C:\Users\[Nome do seu usuário padrão]\Downloads
```

E depois execute ele digitando isto no terminal:

```
python get-pip.py
```

> De qualquer forma se puder evitar o `Programs And Files` ou qualquer pasta que precise de privilégios, será melhor (mais fácil).

Answer (score 2):

## consegui atualizar o meu.

vai nos arquivos do python

> C:\Users[nome_do_usuario]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts

e abre os arquivos do pip

> pip.exe
>
> pip3.7.exe
>
> pip3.exe

entra no cmd e digita

> c:\users[nome_do_usuario]\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

quando atualiza ele ja fica instalado no cmd

espero ter ajudado!boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa criar um arquivo em algum lugar (pode ser no seu desktop) com o nome `get-pip.py` e colocar o código que está [nesse link](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

Após salvar o arquivo, vá no diretorio do arquivo em seu CMD e digite:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Isso vai instalar o pip em seu computador.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma;
Mesmo meu sistema sendo 64x me parece que o git no roda certinho. Ele apresenta a versão do pip 7.0 e ão atualiza nem a pau.  Tive que instalar o python 86x para poder rodar o git e o restante dos pacotes que eu queria como kivy. Nesta versão está com o pip 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Para instalar o pip através de um proxy.

Siga as seguintes instruções.

Acesse:
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Salve o arquivo **get-pip.py** numa pasta e vá no diretorio do arquivo em seu CMD e digite:

1. se o teu proxy for via http e autenticado:
   `set http_proxy=usuario:senha@servidor:porta`
2. se o teu proxy for via https e autenticado:
   `set https_proxy=usuario:senha@servidor:porta`
3. se o teu proxy for via http sem autenticação:
   `set http_proxy=servidor:porta`
4. se o teu proxy for via https sem autenticação:
   `set https_proxy=servidor:porta`

o servidor tem que ter o domínio inteiro, por exemplo, terminando com ".com.br" ou digite o IP dele.

Depois é só digitar:
`python get-pip.py`

Lembre-se de que o python precisa estar na variável `PATH` do teu windows.

E será criada uma pasta Scripts dentro da tua pasta do Python com o pip.

Answer (score -1):

Comigo aconteceu a mesma coisa, um dia anterior a isso, cheguei a instalar o pyinstaller normalmente pelo comando pip, e após isso sem problemas fiz a conversão de um .py, ao tentar fazer outra conversão no dia após, disse que o comando pyInstaller (Responsável por fazer a conversão) não existia, dai fui tentar instalar novamente o PyInstaller pelo comando pip, e disse que o pip não existia também, dai fui tentar executar pelo CMD o comando python, para verificar se estava normal, e acabou que nem o comando ''python'' foi reconhecido, apesar do python estar instalado em meu computador.
Minha solução foi reinstalar o python, e após isso instalar novamente o PyInstaller.

Espero que ajude-o! Boa sorte!